# Get attribute1 value when attribute2 value (using XPath)

Tags: xml, xpath, plsql

In this XML example, I want to get the value of `attribute` `Attr_2` when `Attr_1="A"` (display `str1234`) using XPath.

```html
<ROOT>
     <ELEM_1   Attr_1 = "A"   Attr_2 = "str1234" />
     <ELEM_1   Attr_1 = "B"   Attr_2 = "str5678" />
</ROOT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath for this is `'/ROOT/ELEM_1[@Attr_1 = "A"]/@Attr_2'`

But if you want to do in Oracle DB you have to use [xmltable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions240.htm#SQLRF06232)  or [xmlquery](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions236.htm#SQLRF06209).

```
select * from xmltable('ROOT/ELEM_1[@Attr_1 = "A"]/@Attr_2' passing xmltype('
<ROOT>
     <ELEM_1   Attr_1 = "A"   Attr_2 = "str1234" />
     <ELEM_1   Attr_1 = "B"   Attr_2 = "str5678" />
          <ELEM_1   Attr_1 = "A"   Attr_2 = "next_value" />
</ROOT>') 
columns attr2 varchar2(100) path '.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
/ROOT/ELEM_1[1]  ->  it will return str1234
/ROOT/ELEM_1[2]  ->  it will return str5678
```

OR

```
(/ROOT/ELEM_1)[1]  ->  it will return str1234
(/ROOT/ELEM_1)[2]  ->  it will return str5678
```

OR

```
/ROOT/ELEM_1[1]/@Attr_1  -> it will return A
/ROOT/ELEM_1[2]/@Attr_1  -> it will return B
```

OR

```
/ROOT/ELEM_1[@Attr_1='A']/@Attr_2  -> It will return str1234
/ROOT/ELEM_1[@Attr_1='B']/@Attr_2  -> It will return str5678
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: thx for your response, but in your answer why it returns the value of attr_2 and not of attr_1 without which one is specifiied in XPATH ?